# How to populate an HTML Table with selective MySQL that matches criteria?

Tags: php, html, mysql, datatable

This is my first time posting on here.  I am working on a research project and I am very stumped on where to go next!

I have a database with info from all 50 states.  Is there a way to populate my HTML Table and have it only populate it if the column matches the state page I am on?

Basically if I have the PHP script in the page for Colorado for example, I would like to have some rule that says populate all items from Col3 that match CO.

Thanks for any and all help.  I will certainly mention you on the site when it is done.

My uncle told me I would need a code that is selective but I am not sure what that means.

Comment: This sounds very much possible but you should provide more details about the structure of your table.

Comment: read a basic tutorial about mysql, you will find quickly the answer.

Comment: DISCOVERED THE ANSWER.. Here is an example of how it worked.

Used the $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productScale='1:12'";

Comment: I guess you were born to discover it yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISCOVERED THE ANSWER.. Here is an example of how it worked. 
I used:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productScale='1:12'";
```

Ultimately it boiled down to using a WHERE statement.